# Getting the URL of a Sub version repository

Tags: centos, svn

WE have a couple of SVN repositories on our Centos server, I want to use one of these repositories, the oly issue I can't seem to find the URL of the SVN repositories if I want to checkout the latest copy using RapidSVN on my Ubuntu machine. Is there a way I can find the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it

I did the following

```
less /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Scrolled down to the end and then found the path

Answer (score 0):

`svn+ssh://<hostname>/path/to/svn/repo`

Comment: See I need to find the path of the repository

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you have done a

```
svn info
```

in another working copy? Or isn't there one available?